# Device will not connect to LAN

Tags: wireless-networking

House is 5 years old. Internet outlets for cat5 cables in almost every room. I have a home entertainment system in one room. I added a splitter to the cat5 connection in that room. There are three devices plugged into that splitter. Stereo receiver, blue ray player and the cable box. I had a second stereo system in that room that was not connected to the splitter. That stereo serviced three other rooms with impedance matching volume controls. I had a device (Audioengine) on the second stereo which would receive signals sent from my computer using an Audioengine transmitter. This allowed me to send the same signal to both stereos simultaneously. Either the Audioengine or the second stereo failed. I think it was the stereo because I bought it new in 1994.

I decided to upgrade to an internet ready receiver. First two I sent back because they malfunctioned. Just bought a new one and plugged it in. It is a Harmon Kardon 3700 plain and simple stereo....no video, no surround sound etc.

It searches for the network and returns a message on the display that says ....EMPTY......    I have talked to three techies at Harmon Kardon with no success.

However, my computer recognizes the HK 3700.

Is there a limit to the number of devices the network can handle. These devices are never ALL used at the same time. I changed out the cat5 cable and even moved it to another port on the splitter. I honestly don't think the HK is the problem. Three receivers can't all be bad.

Any ideas?

What is the difference between a splitter and a switch? This may be a switch I am using. When I bought the second device that needed access to the cat5 connection, it was recommended by a salesman at Best Buy. I think it may be a switch.

Thanks

The device is a Linksys SE1500. Is that a switch or a splitter?

Thanks

I appreciate the feedback. My computer recognizes the HK 3700 and did assign it an IP address. I have the owners manual and went through the manual configuration. The IP address that my computer set up appeared as I went through the manual configuration.

If I take the cat5 cable off and start the HK, do you think it will find my computer?

Update.

No one can tell me why the HK 3700 won't recognize the network.

I have learned that the HK 3700 is not WiFi ready. It is supposed to be networkable. I can use a cat5 from my PC to the network rather that depend on WiFi. However, it doesn't matter because the HK 3700 won't recognize the network anyway.

Assuming that the 3700 would recognize the network, I still have to buy a switch to attach to the router. (We had to replace the modem a month or so ago and I was talking to the installation tech about the extra cat5 cables that were not plugged in. He told me that the router we have only supports X connections. The extra cables run to each room in the house. For $150 the company would enable the rest of the rooms. I asked him if he was simply going to add a switch and he looked embarrassed and said yes. I told him no thanks.)

By the time I buy the switch, another cat5 cable or two and spend a lot of time doing installation work I think I am better upgrading to a receiver that is wi-fi ready.

More info.

The router does send out IP addresses. I was going configure the HK manually. Remembering that my PC recognizes the HK, I remembered to look at the HK properties from my PC. It showed an IP address. When I started the manual configuration, the IP address was already there from the auto-configure.

I feel like such a novice. If I buy the switch to add to the router, and I connect my PC via cat5, will the HK 3700 recognize the network. I would think that the HK connectivity would happen regardless of whether I have my PC on WiFi or cat5 connection. What is the HK looking for when it tries to connect?

Thanks

Additionally, when I try to configure the HK manually, the network assigned IP address shows up, but there are several other categories that show IP addresses. Should all of these IP addresses be the same?

Comment: You told us nothing about the network.  So how can we say if there is a limit?  In any event the limit would be hundred of devices.

Comment: I don't mean to sound clueless, but maybe all I am trying to do establish is internet connectivity. My PC is not plugged in to the cat5 outlet. I guess I am all wifi. Come to think of it, the cat5 cables plug in to my AT&T modem in a closet. I really am getting confused.

Comment: I updated my answer, look it over as it should hold the answer to what you need to do to resolve this.

Comment: If you are all WiFi then the CAT5 cable does not serve a purpose.

Comment: What's your status, any solution yet?

Answer (score 9):

Simple: don't use a splitter.

A splitter is not an appropriate networking device in any network.

If you need three devices connected to your LAN then individually connect them to your router. If you don't have enough cable runs then buy a 5-port Gigabit switch for a few pounds.

Internet -> Router/wireless -> house switch + audio equipment switch (on different ports of your router so not too daisychain the switches).

Connect the small switch in the room you need the extra connections and then each device will get its own IP and your kit will work.

Comment: Splitters are appropriate for some types of networks, but not for Ethernet.

Comment: Sorry @user20574 - I was answering from the perspective of Ethernet because the OP's question is about Ethernet  (although only tagged with wireless lol). Thanks for the extra clarification for others though :)

Answer (score 1):

> **Device will not connect to LAN**
>
> It searches for the network and returns a message on the display that
>   says ....EMPTY...... I have talked to three techies at Harmon Kardon
>   with no success.
>
> Is there a limit to the number of devices the network can handle.
>
> These devices are never ALL used at the same time. I changed out the
>   cat5 cable and even moved it to another port on the splitter.

If your network router does not use DHCP to automatically give out IP address to the devices to talk on the data network, then you need to configure the TCP/IP settings as per the [manual/instructions](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/713198/Harman-Kardon-Hk-3700.html?page=13#manual).

Any limits, settings, or configurations contributing to the issue may be a matter of your router and/or network configuration.

I would suggest plugging this device into a **single-terminated Ethernet receptacle** or **directly into the unmanaged** switch which is otherwise plugged directly into the single-terminated Ethernet port wall receptacle. See the [Linksys SE1500 User Guide](http://downloads.linksys.com/downloads/userguide/SE_Series_EU-A_V10b_UG_3425-01528,0.pdf)

> ### [Harman Kardon HK 3700 Owner's Manual: Setting Up The Network; Operations](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/713198/Harman-Kardon-Hk-3700.html?page=13#manual)
>
> ### (Page 13)
>
> **Setting up the Network**
>
> to play Mp3 or wMa media located on dlna-compatible devices connected
>   to the network or use the stereo receiver's internal Internet radio
>   tuner, the stereo receiver must be connected to your home network. If
>   your network uses an automatic Ip address, you should not have to
>   perform any network setup procedures. Once you connect the stereo
>   receiver to your home network, the network should automatically assign
>   an Ip address to the stereo receiver, and the stereo receiver should
>   be automatically connected to your network.
>
> If your stereo receiver does not automatically connect to your
>   network, the stereo receiver will display a Not Connected message when
>   you press the network source button on the remote control.
>
> 1. press the menu button, select network using the up and down buttons of the navigation pad and press OK.the Network menu will appear.
> 2. Select AUTO using the left and Right navigation buttons of the navigation pad and press OK.
> 3. Scroll down to the bottom and select Apply & Save.the stereo receiver will attempt to connect to the network.
>
> If the stereo receiver again fails to connect to the network, you may
>   need to enter your network's settings manually. In this case, you may
>   need to obtain your network's settings from your ISp or network
>   administrator. after obtaining your network's settings
>
> 1. Select IP Configuration and use the Left/Right buttons to change the setting to Manual. the settings such as IP Address, Subnet Mask,
>      Gateway, Primary DNS and Secondary DNS will be activated.
> 2. use the Up/Down buttons to select the correct numbers and make entries for all of these settings.
> 3. Scroll down to the bottom of the page and select Apply & Save.
>      4.press OK.
>
> the stereo receiver will refresh the network connection while it
>   remains On. If the stereo receiver cannot connect to the network using
>   the manual settings, contact your ISp or network administrator for
>   assistance.
>
> **IMPORTANT:** You must select Apply & Save to activate your network settings
>
> <sub>[source](http://www.manualslib.com/manual/713198/Harman-Kardon-Hk-3700.html?page=13#manual)</sub>